# NEXTJS13.4.4 - Cannot find draggable entry with id [1] & data-rbd-draggable-context-id` didnot match. Server: "1"Client: "0"' with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-beautiful-dnd, react-server-components, app-router

How can I fix an issue in Next.js?

```js
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useFinalDataFromForm } from "@/store/useEventAddingData"
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import { MdDelete, MdDragIndicator } from "react-icons/md"
import InputField from "@/components/CustomComponents/InputField"
import { IoMdAdd } from "react-icons/io"
import { HiEllipsisVertical } from "react-icons/hi2"
import { HiOutlineDuplicate } from "react-icons/hi"
import { BiEditAlt } from "react-icons/bi"
import { InputArrProps } from "@/types/propsType"

const Page = () => {
  const finalData = useFinalDataFromForm((state) => state.finalData)
  const [stateFinalData, setStateFinalData] = useState<InputArrProps[]>([])
  const settingsRef = React.useRef<HTMLUListElement | any>(null)

  console.log(stateFinalData)

  // change server side to client side persist data
  useEffect(() => {
    setStateFinalData(finalData)
  }, [finalData])

  // drag and drop position change
  const handleOnDragEnd = (result: any) => {
    if (!result.destination) return
    if (
      result.source.index === result.destination.index &&
      result.source.draggableId === result.destination.draggableId
    )
      return
    const newItems = [...stateFinalData]
    const [reorderedItem] = newItems.splice(result.source.index, 1)
    newItems.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem)
    setStateFinalData(newItems)
  }

  // changing all openSettings to false when user click outside the settings
  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!settingsRef?.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        setStateFinalData(
          stateFinalData.map((item) => ({ ...item, openSettings: false }))
        )
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("mousedown", handle)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handle)
  }, [])

  // based on the Type HTML Input will be rendered
  const handleType = (type: string, placeholder: string) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "text":
        return (
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-[2px]">
            <label htmlFor={placeholder} className="text-xs font-medium">
              {placeholder}
            </label>
            <InputField
              disabled
              type={type}
              id={placeholder}
              name={placeholder}
              inputClassName="disabled:bg-text-icon/5 border border-primary-one w-full lg:w-[300px] xl:w-[500px]"
            />
          </div>
        )

      case "number":
        return (
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-[2px]">
            <label htmlFor={placeholder} className="text-xs font-medium">
              {placeholder}
            </label>
            <InputField
              disabled
              type="number"
              id={placeholder}
              name={placeholder}
              inputClassName="disabled:bg-text-icon/5 border border-primary-one w-full lg:w-[300px] xl:w-[500px]"
            />
          </div>
        )

      case "para":
        return <textarea className="border-2 border-black rounded-lg p-2" />

      case "radio":
        return (
          <>
            <input type="radio" name={type} id={type} />
            <label htmlFor={type} className="mt-1 ml-4">
              something
            </label>
          </>
        )

      default:
        return (
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <label htmlFor={placeholder} className="text-xs">
              {placeholder}
            </label>
            <InputField
              type="text"
              id={placeholder}
              name={placeholder}
              className="border-2 border-black rounded-lg p-2"
            />
          </div>
        )
    }
  }

  // Toogle edit and delete settings
  const handleSettings = (id: number) => {
    const newCustomInput = stateFinalData.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          openSettings: !item.openSettings,
        }
      } else {
        return { ...item, openSettings: false }
      }
    })

    setStateFinalData(newCustomInput)
  }

  // delete the input
  // const handleDelete = (id: number) => {
  //   setStateFinalData((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item.id !== id))
  //   console.log("del")
  // }

  return (
    <>
      <main className="w-full h-[93vh] px-16 py-12">
        <section>
          <h1 className="text-base font-medium mb-5">Form Overview</h1>

          <section className="bg-white shadow-xl px-16 py-12 w-full rounded-lg min-h-screen">
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
              <Droppable droppableId="main-container">
                {(provider) => (
                  <div
                    {...provider.droppableProps}
                    ref={provider.innerRef}
                    className="w-[70%] min-h-screen rounded-md px-4 py-2"
                  >
                    {stateFinalData.map((item: any, index: number) => (
                      <Draggable
                        key={item?.id}
                        draggableId={item?.id.toString()}
                        index={index}
                      >
                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                          <div
                            key={index}
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                          >
                            <div
                              className={`group flex items-center border-black px-3 py-2 rounded-md relative
                              ${
                                snapshot.isDragging && "bg-[#f9f9f9] shadow-xl"
                              }`}
                            >
                              <div className="flex">
                                <IoMdAdd className="text-lg -mt-1 invisible group-hover:visible cursor-pointer" />
                                <MdDragIndicator className="text-lg -mt-1 invisible group-hover:visible cursor-pointer" />
                              </div>

                              <div className="cursor-pointer">
                                {handleType(item.type, item.name)}
                              </div>

                              <div
                                className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-primary-one/5 rounded-md"
                                onClick={() => handleSettings(item.id)}
                              >
                                <HiEllipsisVertical className="text-xl" />
                              </div>

                              {item.openSettings && (
                                <ul
                                  className="bg-white text-xs p-2 flex flex-col absolute -right-6 gap-1 top-4 rounded-lg z-[20]
                                shadow-[1px_1px_15px_0px_rgba(106,107,108,0.18),0px_8px_10px_-6px_rgba(0,0,0,0.1)] cursor-pointer"
                                  ref={settingsRef}
                                >
                                  <li
                                    className="flex gap-2 p-1 items-center rounded-md bg-primary-one/5 hover:bg-primary-one/40
                                  hover:text-white "
                                  >
                                    <HiOutlineDuplicate />
                                    <span>Duplicate</span>
                                  </li>
                                  <li
                                    className="flex gap-2 p-1 items-center rounded-md text-primary-one bg-primary-one/10 
                                  hover:bg-primary-one hover:text-white"
                                  >
                                    <BiEditAlt />
                                    Edit
                                  </li>
                                  <li
                                    className="flex gap-2 p-1 items-center rounded-md text-red-400 bg-red-300/20 
                                    hover:bg-red-400 hover:text-white"
                                    // onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}
                                  >
                                    <MdDelete />
                                    Delete
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              )}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </Draggable>
                    ))}
                    {provider.placeholder}
                  </div>
                )}
              </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
          </section>
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Iam have issue in the above code . whenever i try to drag the specfic id based element is shows error in the console  **Invariant failed: Cannot find draggable entry with id [id-number]** and **data-rbd-draggable-context-id` did not match. Server: "1" Client: "0"' with react-beautiful-dnd and next.js(APP ROUNTER 13.4.4)**

Help me to fix it

**HAPPY CODING**

Iam have issue in the above code . whenever i try to drag the specfic id based element is shows error in the console  **Invariant failed: Cannot find draggable entry with id [id-number]** and **data-rbd-draggable-context-id` did not match. Server: "1" Client: "0"' with react-beautiful-dnd and next.js(APP ROUNTER 13.4.4)**

Help me to fix it

**HAPPY CODING**

Iam have issue in the above code . whenever i try to drag the specfic id based element is shows error in the console  **Invariant failed: Cannot find draggable entry with id [id-number]** and **data-rbd-draggable-context-id` did not match. Server: "1" Client: "0"' with react-beautiful-dnd and next.js(APP ROUNTER 13.4.4)**

Help me to fix it

**HAPPY CODING**

Iam have issue in the above code . whenever i try to drag the specfic id based element is shows error in the console  **Invariant failed: Cannot find draggable entry with id [id-number]** and **data-rbd-draggable-context-id` did not match. Server: "1" Client: "0"' with react-beautiful-dnd and next.js(APP ROUNTER 13.4.4)**

Help me to fix it

**HAPPY CODING**